Playwright Geolocation not setting up properly
When trying to set Geo-location using Playwright to a specific Long-Lat, say for New York, London, or Madrid, the provided Long-Lat input is not set to page/context and the default location is shown only
I am trying to emulate geo-location with playwright using this documentation. The Geo-location permission is granted but the browser does not emulation the provided location, and instead it only shows me my current location.
First I used the test.use which sets the parameters for page object by default and it did not work, then I tried to set it for the context manually inside the test and that did not work either.
Here is my test case
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test.use({
    geolocation: { longitude: 41.890221, latitude: 12.492348 },
    permissions: ['geolocation'],
});


test("Change Locale Concept", async ({ page, context }) => {

    // Go to the location-checking website
    //await page.goto('https://mylocation.org/');
    await context.setGeolocation({ longitude: 48.858455, latitude: 2.294474 });
    await page.goto("https://www.bing.com/maps");
    // Take a screenshot to verify settings
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot-us.png' });

    // Inject a script to log the geolocation
    const geolocation = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                position => resolve(position.coords),
                error => reject(error)
            );
        });
    });

    // Log the geolocation
    console.log(`Latitude: ${geolocation.latitude}, Longitude: ${geolocation.longitude}`);

    // Check the permissions of the page
    const permissions = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const permissionNames = ['geolocation', 'notifications', 'camera', 'microphone'];
        const results = {};
        for (const name of permissionNames) {
            try {
                const result = await navigator.permissions.query({ name });
                results[name] = result.state;
            } catch (e) {
                results[name] = 'permission not available';
            }
        }
        return results;
    });

    // Log the permissions
    console.log('Permissions:', permissions);

    // Validate the geolocation permission
    expect(permissions.geolocation).toBe('granted');

});




Then I am trying to see what permission I have and the Geo-location permission is granted to the page/context. But the Long-Lat does not seems to be set as per provided data.
here is the output I get against the above test case
Latitude: undefined, Longitude: undefined
Permissions: {
  geolocation: 'granted',
  notifications: 'denied',
  camera: 'denied',
  microphone: 'denied'
}


The core issue is that there are many ways to determine or roughly infer one's geolocation with varying precision:

GPS (on mobile devices, arguably most precise)
Wi-Fi positioning
IP address
Device Geolocation API (what we assume is the main thing that matters)
Other

The second issue is that different services will use different techniques, and what's worse - they may change at any time!
Automation scripts may set the Geolocation, but Google Maps (or another service) will look at other factors or their combination.
Nevertheless, here is a script that works as of the time of this answer. The key thing is setting userAgent to a mobile device. Other mobile devices work. But 'Desktop Chrome' or other Desktop Devices won't.
You'll have to experiment further.
import { test, chromium, devices } from '@playwright/test';

test('Test Geolocation', async () => {

    const iPad = devices['iPad (gen 7) landscape'];        
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 2000 });

    const context = await browser.newContext({
        userAgent: iPad.userAgent,  // here!
        locale: 'en_GB',
        geolocation: { longitude: -0.118092, latitude: 51.509865 },  // London
        permissions: ['geolocation']
    });

    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://maps.google.com');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept all' }).click();
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Stay on web' }).click();
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'London-iPad.png' });
});


